# Display data from user uid with Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to recover data from the uid and then display them in RecyclerView.

I managed to recover the child/parent  under Withdrawal thanks to the uid.

This is what it looks like in Java:

```
referenceWithdraw = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Withdraw");
Query queryUid = referenceWithdraw.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(user.getUid());
    queryUid.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class)

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            ///
        }
   });
```

`String id = ...` retrieves the child value.

So far everything is fine except when I add this under the
`String id = ...` :

```
referenceWithdraw.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        WithdrawProfile profile = snapshot.getValue(WithdrawProfile.class);
        list.add(profile);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I have this error appearing in my Logcat :

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertInteger(CustomClassMapper.java:364)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(CustomClassMapper.java:290)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:215)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.pckage.app.android.withdraw.Withdraw$1.onDataChange(Withdraw.java:62)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

And finally here is my WithdrawProfile :

```
public class WithdrawProfile {
    private String date, email, status, id;
    private int prize;
    public WithdrawProfile(){}

    public WithdrawProfile(String date, String email, String status, String id, int prize) {
        this.date = date;
        this.email = email;
        this.status = status;
        this.id = id;
        this.prize = prize;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(int prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }
}
```

My database :

```
{
  "Daily" : {
    "KuTKHdv1qeYS1NeQVZlqYdZYyNi1" : {
      "date" : "07/01/2022"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "KuTKHdv1qeYS1NeQVZlqYdZYyNi1" : {
      //Other value
      "uid" : "KuTKHdv1qeYS1NeQVZlqYdZYyNi1"
    }
  },
  "Withdraw" : {
    "-MszSsu9rn6XzRMUNgTc" : {
      "date" : "09/01/2022",
      "id" : "-MszSsu9rn6XzRMUNgTc",
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "prize" : "1000",
      "statut" : "Pending",
      "uid" : "KuTKHdv1qeYS1NeQVZlqYdZYyNi1"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please edit your question to show: 1) the complete stack trace of the error message, 2) the JSON that you are reading when the exception occurs (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: It's done Sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in reading this value from the database:

```
"prize" : "1000",
```

In your Java class you define `prize` as an int:

```
public int getPrize() {
    return prize;
}

public void setPrize(int prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
}
```

But in your database it is stored as a string value: `"1000"`. Since they're not the same type, Firebase can't read the `prize` value and throws an error.

The solution is to either store the prize as a (whole) number:

```
"prize" : 1000,
```

Or to make it a string in your Java code too:

```
private String prize;

...

public String getPrize() {
    return prize;
}

public void setPrize(String prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
}
```

Comment: Oh I just edited, it works perfectly. Excuse me for this careless error. Thank you very much !!

Comment: It was thanks to the additional information that I was able to find the problem, so all 